# How can I dynamically display a stream position?

Tags: dynamic, streams

If I create a stream,

```
str = StringToStream["how can I dynamically display the stream position"];
Read[str, Word]

"how"
```

then, when I use,

```
Dynamic[StreamPosition[str]]
```

The output will not dynamically update the current state of the stream position.

Any ideas?

Comment: Same issue with `Dynamic[Streams[ ]]`

Comment: A workaround, of course `Dynamic[Refresh[Streams[], UpdateInterval -> 1]]`

Comment: The stream `str` contains only stream ID and it never changes. You can obtain full stream information with ``Internal`StreamInformation[str]``. Unfortunately, It doesn't solve the problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To not prompt `Dynamic` each second or something, let's create useless variable that will prompt it.

```
Dynamic[T`r; StreamPosition[str]]
read = (T`r = Read[##]) &;
read[str, Word]
```

Comment: Veggy, veggy nice!

Comment: Well done! could you perhaps explain the mechanics behind these notations? i.e. the " ` "

Comment: @peter I just used `T` contex to not pollute the default ``Global` ``.

Comment: @Kuba cool, thanks